# Allowing file://localhost to be the origin of authentication request for YouTube API

Tags: api, youtube

I'm getting this error: 
Error: invalid_request
Invalid parameter value for origin: Invalid scheme: file

I've started Chrome with disable-web-security, but no luck. Any suggestions? Or should I switch to using an API key instead of OAuth?